# How to enable or disable network card and send packet using Assembly language?

Tags: assembly

if i know IRQ number of network card in window XP, How to enable or disable network card and send packet using x86 Assembly language without depending on MASM or other libraries?

i googled said using something like in al,0x21 or 0x20

Comment: The libraries are there for a reason:You have to use different procedures for different cards.However, I would also like to find some documentation on wireless network cards, there seems to be very hard to find on the internet.Cool name by the way:)

Comment: Depends on the network card. What kind of network card is it? manufacturer, type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from usermode application you cant use ports, only driver can access ports in windows nt. Second exactly port number depend on network card. There arent any generic specification for hardware implementation here. But windows architecture hide this hardware specific details by NDIS miniport driver. And you can write driver, that communicate with miniport by documented interface and sent handmade packets over network.

Comment: if not in window, how about doing it in bootloader or kernel image